# Develop with Rails 3 when Rails 4 is already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to begin local development of this [open-source project](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe), but it uses Rails 3.2.21, and I already have Rails 4.x installed. How can I specify that I want to work with Rails 3 only when working on this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a ruby version manager, something like [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/), [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), each doc will tell you what to do.

This way you could have different ruby versions installed, and with bundler you could use different rails versions according to the Gemfile.

Just add a `.ruby-version` file inside the project root, and the version manager should detect it.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that I had rbenv insstalled but I just realized it got the version automatically

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile specify the rails version you want that project to use:

```
# Gemfile

gem "rails", "~> 3.2.21"
```

Comment: It may create issue for other gem compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To use the specific rails version with your app you can do this:

```
rails _3.2.21_ myApp
```

If you don't already have rails 3.2.21 installed just run this:

```
gem install 'rails' -v '3.2.21'
```

Comment: Hi but Im not going to create a new app I already have the app cloned from github

Comment: @SsouLlesS, I updated my answer. Does that work for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you will change the rails version directly in Gemfile, it may raise issue for compatibility later:

Instead use RVM or other related version manager and after isntalling use below command:
 - rvm use 1.9.3
 - bundle install
 - Then mention the version in Gem file